# How can I use ingress-nginx via Helm on custom k8s install without LoadBalancer support?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I installed k8s on Ubuntu 18.04. This instance is on a no-frills host that has no concept of load balancers.

I installed the nginx ingress via: `helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name my-nginx`

As you can see below, there is a service line that shows a `LoadBalancer` type service pending.

```
$ kubectl get svc
ingress-nginx-nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.110.139.78    <pending>     80:31310/TCP,443:31820/TCP
ingress-nginx-nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.105.146.132   <none>        80/TCP
```

Is there a way to setup the nginx-ingress w/o a `LoadBalancer` service, preferably with Helm? If not, a workaround without Helm would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress

According to official docs of chart you can configure service type through `controller.service.type` property and setting it to NodePort instead of LoadBalancer